# Accessing response header fields

Tags: angularjs, http-headers

Right now I have a RESTful API that's returning a refreshed JWT Authorization token every time my endpoint is accessed by my AngularJS service. I want to have a user's browser save this token (as part of the session and in `localStorage`) by accessing it through the response object created by `$httpProvider.intercepters`. My issue is I don't know how to get to that response object. I know my browser sees the response header and all the custom values I've put in there:

[image: Response header fields]

I tried accessing `response.headers` and `response.config.headers` but neither one contained my values. Obviously the browser sees it, but how do I get to those values?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From AngularJS, [$http documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#general-usage):

You can access the headers from success and error callback like:

1) If you are making request like:

```
// Simple GET request example:
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/someUrl',
  // This header will be sent as a part of the request
  headers: {
    'name-of-header': 'header-data'
  },
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // Access the headers like
    var headerData = response.headers('name-of-header');
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    // Access the headers like
    var headerData = response.headers('name-of-header');
  });
```

2) Using interceptors:

```
// alternatively, register the interceptor via an anonymous factory
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q) {
  return {
   'request': function(config) {
       config.headers = config.headers || {};
       // Send new header
       config.headers['my-header'] = 'my-header-data';

       // Don't forget to return the config
       return config;
    },

    'response': function(response) {
       // Get header from response
       var myHeaderData = response.headers('my-header');

       // Don't forget to return response object or a promise.'
       return response || $q.when(response);
    }
  };
});
```

Note: The custom headers will be visible in the same domain. However, for the cross-domain request, the server has to send `Access-Control-Expose-Headers: foo-bar-header, ...` header with the header name to expose as the value and that will make the custom header visible to the `$http` module. Read more about [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS). Also, read about the [Access-Control-Expose-Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers) and the [security considerations](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#security-considerations).

Comment: I appreciate your including how to get the field value from a regular response header; I'll definitely keep that in mind for the future.

I tried `console.log(response.headers('Authorization'))` but that returned null.

Comment: I noticed in the browser the Etag header always had a valid value so for grins I put in  `console.log('Etag: ' + response.headers('Etag'));`. I noticed that statement always returned a value when the browser was processing a HTML view (and of course the two matched). But when it came to my JSON output it was null.

Comment: 'null' value is always returned for any non-existent headers. Make sure that the server is sending that header.

Comment: I'm using Chrome Developer Tools for looking at header values, and that screenshot I included in my OP is showing that I'm getting values back. I've also got some print statements in my endpoint to return the token and that value from server exactly matches that in the "non-existent" header value in the browser.

Comment: Can you share the AngularJS source code? Anyways here is a CodePen link and this showcases the above mentioned solution. http://codepen.io/gauravmahto/pen/qrbzzm

Comment: FYI this issue is with a personal app I have (API I wrote in Ruby on Rails). Before I left the office today I did the same thing with the app I'm writing for my day job and it worked! I saw the value being returned from `response.headers('Authorization')` (API I wrote in Python/Flask).

Comment: Here's the snippet:
`'response': function (response) {
                        if ((typeof(response.data.Authorization) !== 'undefined') && (typeof($localStorage.currentUser) !== 'undefined')) {
                            $localStorage.currentUser.token = 'JWT ' + response.data.Authorization.split(' ').pop();
                        }
                        console.log(response.headers('Authorization'));
                        return response;
                    }`
FYI I read from response.data.Authorization because at the time I wrote it I needed a workaround.

Comment: The app at work is set up with my endpoints and static SPA files accessible from a single host and port. The app I'm working on here has them on the same host but different ports. I imagine that should make no difference but I'm grasping at straws.

Comment: Remember the custom headers are only visible if you are on the same domain. In case of cross-domain request, the server needs to add `Access-Control-Expose-Headers: foo-bar` header with any value and that will make custom headers available to $http module. Read more about CORS https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS. Also, read about security considerations https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#security-considerations

Comment: That's exactly what I discovered. Thank you for your help! I added this to my nginx location section: `add_header Access-Control-Expose-Headers "Authorization";`.

Comment: Glad to be of any help!

Comment: And for anyone who happens to stumble upon this thread... To look at all the content in the response header it's not `response.headers` - it's `response.headers()`.

Comment: @Gaurav I got the output

Answer (score 0):

This is simple..and it can achieve by using the following methods.

```
function SuccessCB(response){
// securityID is response header param name.
var resheader = response.header['securityID'];
}
```